# how can I access a PHP variable into the form fields

Tags: php

Here is the php code. I am trying to echo php variable into the form field textbox attribute.

```
<?php
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

        $title=$result["title"];
        $date=$result["date"];
        $body=$result["body"];
        $email=$result["email"];
        $id=$result["id"];
//can i use the $id variable into the form field like bellow 
//if not then how so    


echo"<form action="" method="post">";
//Here i m using  $id variable  
echo "<input type="test" name="test" value='<?php echo "$id"?>'/>";
echo "<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please read about how to escape quotes in strings first ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't use additional php tags when already in php: just concat it as a regular var

```
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"test\" name=\"test\" value='" . $id . "'/>";//Here i m using $id       variable    
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: why concat? `echo "..... $id ..."` works just as well. Any decent modern editor can properly syntax highlight that as well. If the var might be confused with other text, there's `echo " .... {$id} ..."` brace notation available as well.

Comment: what ?! but he write echo inside an echo !!!

Comment: I'm not arguing with that. I'm saying that `echo "x" . $id . "x"` is pointless, when you can simply have `echo "x{$id}x"` instead without the extra quotes/concat operations.

Comment: this is just a coding convenience. it's not a question of right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question you should remove the  tags inside your code.

Change line 11 to:

```
echo '<input type="test" name="test" value="' . htmlentities($id) . '"/>';
```

If the id is coming from a user input you need to sanitize it with htmlentities() or else you'll open up your site to an xss (Cross site scripting) vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put the variable in ""

```
echo "<input type='test' name='test' value='{$id?}>'/>";
```

this should work

and be careful of using double quote in side double quote without escaping them

Answer (score 0):

How you are using echo function, you must exclude the echo internally and scape the double quote:

```
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"test\" name=\"test\" value=\"{$id}\" />";//Here i m using $id  variable    
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Anoter form and more clearly is closing php tag and open it after html code:

```
?> 
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="test" name="test" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
```